# Archive SQL Server Data in EBS to Glacier

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-glacier, aws-ebs

We have a SQL Server hosted on EC2 that has multiple databases. The data for all the databases is stored in an EBS volume. We have a requirement where some of the databases are not in use and the data associated with those inactive databases can be archived to cheaper storage solutions i.e. use the EBS volume for active databases only.

My solution is to take the `*.mdb` files for in-active databases and persist them in Glacier. Post that, delete the inactive databases from the SQL Server instance, there by reducing the storage size in EBS. This also means I can use the storage in EBS, from deleting the inactive databases, by adding more active databases into the instance.

Is this approach and understanding correct? Are there any best practices that for this requirement.

regards
-Ravi

Comment: `.mdb` is an **MS Access** database file - SQL Server uses `.ldf`, `.mdf`, `.ndf` files by default

Comment: true. My mistake. I assume the SQL server transaction log file need not be archived. It will just be the data file *.mdf. Thanks for pointing it out.